# Difference between silverlight file upload and asp.net file upload control?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, file-upload, azure, silverlight-4.0

I am trying to upload a large file of size more than 30 mb , If i upload using silverlight file upload control it hardly takes a minute to upload 30 mb file to server , If i try to upload the same file using asp.net file upload control or telerik rad upload control it takes for ever to upload the file to azure storage  , May i know what is difference between these two controls , what is so special about silverlight control that upload happens so fast ?

The reason why i am trying asp.net file upload is i need to send a mail immediately after the fileupload is completed with filename and file location  , I can do this in asp.net code behind by capturing the filename in code behind , how can i achieve this functionality using silver light fileupload control

Answer (score 0):

Have you look into the proper configuration on the controls? some controls have configuration like sending the data by chunk. sending data by chunk may affect the request/response time of server to client and vice versa.

Answer (score -1):

As per my knowledge in Silverlight you can uploaded file on server by WCF service. In WCF service where you just uploaded file content data in bytes format. While you using uploading web page at that time other control like textbox, dropdown etc that's carry viewstate. So uploading your file content with that data are also uploaded on server, so it will affect for uploading speed by web form.

Comment: can i capture uploaded filename using silverlight file upload control in code behind?